# How to get posts filtered by category in SiteFinity 8

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I'm trying to get post information from SiteFinity through my custom widget (ascx control). I need to filter these posts by category. I'm fairly new with SiteFinity and appreciate any input or direction that can be given.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to achieve this. Please, see code below:

```
BlogsManager blogsManager = BlogsManager.GetManager();
TaxonomyManager manager = TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
HierarchicalTaxon taxo = manager.GetTaxa<HierarchicalTaxon>().Where(t => t.Taxonomy.TaxonName == "Category" && t.Name == "YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME").SingleOrDefault();
System.Linq.IQueryable<BlogPost> blogPosts = blogsManager.GetBlogPosts().Where(b => b.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && b.GetValue<TrackedList<Guid>>("Category").Contains(taxo.Id));

foreach (BlogPost blogPostObj in blogPosts) {
//HERE YOU CAN USE BLOG POST INFORMATION
}
```